# Applet copy/paste not working after upgrading JRE 1.7

Tags: java, security, applet, right-click

I have applet which loads form. The form has text, textarea, dropdown, checkbox controls. After upgrading to JRE 1.7 Im not able to right click inside my text fields to copy/paste any content.

My JAR file is dually signed and security permissions set. I have also tried the workaround by changing settings in .java.policy file :

```
// "standard" properies that can be read by anyone
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
```

Interestingly enough I can do copy/paste by right click inside my TEXTAREA control but not inside any other control.

Any suggestions/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions/advice?

- Abandon applets completely<sup>1</sup>, or
- Lower the requirements (no 'right click').

They were always a PITA, and that increased by an order of magnitude with the recent security updates.

1. If the functionality does not need to be embedded in a web page, you might have more luck with a free floating `JFrame` launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  OTOH, it might have also become subject to the 'no right click' philosophy.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for answer! :) Abandon applets completely? not possible as abandoning them will require a big re-writing of code. Lower the requirements(no 'right click')? yes acceptable under compulsion as there is no other way :(