# Java warning despite applet being signed properly

Tags: java, security, applet, digital-signature

I have JAR which is properly signed  with a valid certificate from a trusted company. Im running an applet using HTML applet tag. My Manifest file includes following permissions:

```
Application-Name ="XYZ"
Permissions="all-permissions"
Codebase="*"
Trusted-Library="true"
```

I get the following warning message when running applet in browser:

[image: Java Warning for my signed applet]

I do not want this message to appear when my users open my applet. Can you advise me why this warning message is appearing and how to avoid it from appearing for my users?

Thanks!

Comment: Due to recent security incidents, you cannot anymore.

Comment: do you mean this is there to notify users to make a concious decision whether to run the applet or not and it is not a security threat warning kind of?

Comment: The user must now consciously decide, and it is a security threat warning. They may well not trust you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to avoid it from appearing for my users?

There is no way to avoid it.  It is the choice of the user as to whether to run trusted code, and the decision of Sun/Oracle that they should be prompted.

Why exactly does the applet require `all-permissions`?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. all-permissions because we wanted let users do right click copy/paste from inside applet. Though Right click menu seems to have been blocked by Java in 1.7

Comment: Copy/paste can be supported in a sand-boxed applet since 1.6.0_10+.  The warnings will not disappear, but they will be less scary.

Comment: ok. If I give permissions: sandbox , the warning message will say..."the application will run with restricted access....". yes I agree that this message will not scare users.

As an apart, the right click menu is not working in JRE/JDK 1.7u45. I extensively searched but did not find a single instance where it is working. My problem for this emanates from my need for my users to be able to right click inside my form fields and do copy/paste. Surprisingly it works for TEXTAREA but not for other controls like TEXTFIELD etc. My forms are in AWT.

Comment: I am not sure.  Review [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8513818/418556) & the linked OTN thread and perhaps that will get you further.  I am a little hazy on the details of those answers & could not be bothered reviewing them right now.

Comment: The link is old(2011). My applets work fine for right click in JRE 1.6 but the same do not in JRE 1.7. So it seems that Java 1.7 has completely blocked the right click inside applets.

I discussed this issue [here](http://www.java-forums.org/java-applets/83695-applet-copy-paste-not-working-after-upgrading-jre-1-7-a.html)
and [here](https://www.java.net//forum/topic/general-programming-help/applet-copypaste-not-working-after-upgrading-jre-17) . But got no solutions.

Comment: Yes, my bad.  I was more concerned with 'copy/paste' than 'right click' when forming the thread/code etc. for that thread. If 'right click' is a definite requirement, I am at a loss beyond a suspicion that it will not be practical to implement it in a sand-boxed applet.  Are you also seeing the same in the trusted version, or only the sand-boxed variant?

Comment: Im seeing this in all variants whether sandboxed or trusted. And I tested this for different applets signed with different digital security certificates. They all work for right click in 1.6 but do not in 1.7.

Comment: Reviewing the original it seems to me that a) your original question is *answered*, and b) You should ask a new question in regard to 'right click'.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Im marking yours as answer. I have already discussed it on this forums but did not get any answers. The link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086892/applet-copy-paste-not-working-after-upgrading-jre-1-7)